# Cyclic shift of a pandas series

Tags: python, pandas

I am using the shift method for a data series in pandas 
 [(documentation)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html).

Is it possible do a cyclic shift, i.e. the first value become the last value, in one step?

```
>>> input
Out[20]: 
5     0.995232
15    0.999794
25    1.006853
35    0.997781
45    0.981553
Name: vRatio, dtype: float64

>>> input.shift()
Out[21]: 
5          NaN
15    0.995232
25    0.999794
35    1.006853
45    0.997781
Name: vRatio, dtype: float64
```

desired output:

```
Out[21]: 
5     0.981553
15    0.995232
25    0.999794
35    1.006853
45    0.997781
Name: vRatio, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use [`np.roll`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html) to cycle the index values and pass this as the values to [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html#pandas.DataFrame.reindex):

```
In [23]:
df.reindex(index=np.roll(df.index,1))

Out[23]:
         vRatio
index          
45     0.981553
5      0.995232
15     0.999794
25     1.006853
35     0.997781
```

If you want to preserve your index then you can just overwrite the values again using `np.roll`:

```
In [25]:
df['vRatio'] = np.roll(df['vRatio'],1)
df

Out[25]:
         vRatio
index          
5      0.981553
15     0.995232
25     0.999794
35     1.006853
45     0.997781
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a slight modification of @EdChum 's great answer, which I find more useful in situations where I want to avoid an assignment:

```
pandas.DataFrame(np.roll(df.values, 1), index=df.index)
```

or for Series:

```
pandas.Series(np.roll(ser.values, 1), index=ser.index)
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this without using a single step:

```
>>> output = input.shift()
>>> output.loc[output.index.min()] = input.loc[input.index.max()]
>>> output
Out[32]: 
5     0.981553
15    0.995232
25    0.999794
35    1.006853
45    0.997781
Name: vRatio, dtype: float64
```