# Shifting a Row in Python-Pandas

Tags: python

I am new to Pandas and I have a question which I could not fix it by myself.
This is my column

```
0       12.000000

1       21.540659

2       19.122413

3     16.568042

4     17.082154

5     15.932148

6     15.226856

7     14.400521

8     17.900962

9     17.169741

10          NaN
```

and I want to shift it by one row.The expected result should be looks like this:

```
0           NaN

1     12.000000

2     21.540659

3     19.122413

4     16.568042

5     17.082154

6     15.932148

7     15.226856

8     14.400521

9     17.900962

10    17.169741
```

Here is my code:

```
data['A']=pd.Series(a).shift(periods=1)
```

`a` is a list and I convert it to the pandas series to add a new column as an "A" in my dataframe. Howerevr I need to shift my rows without losing the last data.

Comment: Why don't you simply insert to the array a *before* you make it a Series object?

Comment: Could you explain more?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wait now? Doesn't this work?

```
data["A"] = data["A"].shift(1)
```

Comment: If you has a=list('ABCDE'), you would lose 'E'.

Comment: But OP's result loses the last `NaN`.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC,

You could pad your Series creation with an extra row then shift:

```
data['A'] = pd.Series(a+[pd.np.nan]).shift(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`np.roll`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html) for that.

Answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31561412/cyclic-shift-of-a-pandas-series?answertab=active#tab-top), check the link for details.